# About namespace registering in javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, registration

I'm new to javascript world. I'm analyzing the code explained [here](http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/16/firefox-extensions-global-namespace-pollution/) to avoid pollution at the global level when writing a firefox extension.
When the code

```
1. // Namespace registration  
2. this.ns = function(fn) {  
3. var ns = {};  
4. namespaces.push(fn, ns);  
5. return ns;  
6. };
```

is executing I don't understand:
1) why the code declare **ns = {}** at line 3
2) why the code **return ns** at line 5
3) which function is receiving the returned ns{} and how this function will use it
4) ns{} is always the same(?) for every namespace registered, so why is pushed in namespaces array together with fn parameter and then provided when the code is executing fn.apply(ns) as it would be different every time?
Sorry for my poor english and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most typical way of implementing namespaces but it's an interesting one. I'll try to answer your questions as clear as possible:

**1.** Because the function which is pushed in the array namespaces needs to have own context and not to pollute the global namespace. You can declare:

```
extension.ns(function () {
   this.myVar = 5;
});
```

Each time your anonymous function is being invoked `this` will be the `ns` object corresponding to the given function. That's because of the way the function is invoked (using `apply`).

**2.** The code returns `ns` because you may need to add extra properties or methods to the context object.

**3.** In the given example none. If you use:

```
function foo() {
   alert(this.bar);
}

var ns = extension.ns(foo);
ns.bar = 'foobar';
```

when the function `foo` is invoked from the extension you should get alert with text: "foobar" (`this` in the function body will be the `ns` object).

**4.** Each `ns` is different. When you use `ns = {};` each time you create different object, the reference is pointing to different objects, so each context for each declared function is different (for context you can think of the `ns` object).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to reanalyze the code with the extra information you gave me.

Comment: You're welcome if you have extra questions I'll be glad to help.